# tcp ip client server connection to receive XML data in php

Tags: php, xml, sockets, tcp

Hi guys how are you doing. 
Please i have this network device that sends an XML data to the network, so i'm  currently working on a monitoring application that will connect permanently to this device to receive an XML data as long as the device keeps sending the data into the network the moment it is connected.

I have used php socket programming, and my application connects to the server , tho it keeps sending the xml data but in multiples and i have tried find a way to send the XML data once it loops through and only resend when the device send another one but its not working that way. Below is the code :

```
  <?php
//timeout limit
set_time_limit(0);

//Creating Socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "<br />";
} else {
    echo "OK.<br />";
}

echo "Attempting to connect to the socket'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, '192.168.43.50', 10001);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.<br />Reason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "<br />";
} else {
    echo "OK.<br />";
}
$in = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r<br />";
$in .= "Host: 192.168.43.50\r\n<br />";
$in .= "Content-Type: application/xml; encoding=UTF-8\r\n";
$in .= "Accept: application/xml\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r<br />\r<br />";
$out= '';

echo "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
echo "OK.<br />";

echo "Reading response:<br /><br />";

while ($out = socket_read($socket, PHP_BINARY_READ g)) {
    //$result= simplexml_load_string($out) or die ("Error: Cannot create object");
//print_r ($result);
    echo htmlspecialchars ($out)."\r\n /<br /><br />";


echo "Closing socket...";
socket_close($socket);
echo "OK.<br /><br />";

?>
```

I used fsocket, i also receive the XML once like have wanted but the connection terminates and i dont get to receive the XML data continually.
Heres the code

```
<?php
 $fp = fsockopen("192.168.43.50", 10001, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)";
} else {
    $wait = true;    
    $out = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

    // [1] disable blocking
    stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);
    fwrite($fp, $out);

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $r = fgets($fp);
        echo htmlspecialchars ($r);
        if (!strcmp($r, "")){                
            if (!$wait) {
                // [2] has recieved data on this socket before
                break;
            }
        } else {
            $wait = false;
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: There's really no reason to write your own HTTP client library when PHP has [cURL built-in](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). If you need a persistent connection, try leveraging an existing protocol like [Socket.io](https://socket.io) which has implementations in a multitude of languages, PHP included.